# VBA - Code to save an Excel file in XLS version, using the same name as the original file

Tags: excel, vba

So, basically the title. I have a macro that has to remove columns and format a CSV file, and later saves it as XLSX. My problem is, I can not seem to find a code for the macro so save such file with the same name as the original.

I need to have both Excel files saved as CSV and XLSX. Here is my code:

```
ChDir "C:\Users\RenJeo3\Desktop"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\RenJeo3\Desktop\" & "(thisworkbook.fullName)" & ".xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: You have the syntax for the FileName:= part wrong. Do you want to save the .xlsx version in the same folder as the .csv file?

Comment: Hi! Correct. I am learning how to record and clean the macros, so I might have deleted something by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "csv" with "xlsx"

```
Dim s As String, NewFileNm As String
s = ThisWorkbook.Name
NewFileNm = Replace(s, "csv", "xlsx")
MsgBox NewFileNm
```

You should also be able to remove this part of the code since the filenm now has .xlsx

remove
`& ".xlsx"`

Comment: It's not clear from the OP's information whether they want to store the .xlsx file in the same folder as the .csv file.

Comment: Ah yes, full name would also include the directory, name would suffice. Point I was making was the csv need to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks to both, this really helped!